# printing the array by method call

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Q5 
{
    public static void main(String[] args){

         double[] v1 = {5, 2, 3};
         double[] v2 = {-1, 2, 0};
         double[]sum = (v1[i] * v2[i]);

             System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum));

    }

         public static double[] product(double[] v1, double[] v2){

              double[] sum = new double[v1.length];

              for(int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++){
                  sum[i]= v1[i] * v2[i];
              }
              return sum;
        }

}
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what it is you are trying to achieve. What have you tried so far? What isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your 'product' method in your 'main'

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] v1 = {5, 2, 3};
        double[] v2 = {-1, 2, 0};
        double[] sum = product(v1 , v2);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum));
    }
```